# ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic3

IONIC 3 error build IOS
Ld /Users/brunodourado/mobile/condovox/platforms/ios/build/emulator/CondoVox.app/CondoVox normal x86_64
    cd /Users/brunodourado/Mobile/condovox/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/brunodourado/Mobile/condovox/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/brunodourado/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/brunodourado/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/:/Users/brunodourado/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.1.sdk -L/Users/brunodourado/mobile/condovox/platforms/ios/build/emulator -F/Users/brunodourado/mobile/condovox/platforms/ios/build/emulator -FCondoVox/Plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated -filelist /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CondoVox.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CondoVox_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CondoVox.swiftmodule -ObjC -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/CondoVox.app.xcent /Users/brunodourado/mobile/condovox/platforms/ios/build/emulator/libCordova.a -weak_framework ImageIO -framework CoreLocation -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework MessageUI -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleIPhoneUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -lc++ -lz -framework AddressBook -lsqlite3.0 -framework Security -weak_framework WebKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CondoVox_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/brunodourado/mobile/condovox/platforms/ios/build/emulator/CondoVox.app/CondoVox
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVIonicKeyboard._shrinkView in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVIonicKeyboard._disableScrollingInShrinkView in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVIonicKeyboard._keyboardResizes in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVIonicKeyboard._hideFormAccessoryBar in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVIonicKeyboard._paddingBottom in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVIonicKeyboard._keyboardIsVisible in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVIonicKeyboard in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVIonicKeyboard in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVIonicKeyboard._isWK in:
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-570CCCFD6535B6C5.o
    /Users/brunodourado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CondoVox-dfnekwtnodleuvelwrytyprmscys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CondoVox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CondoVox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVIonicKeyboard-4B03F88A9363B4C8.o
ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/brunodourado/mobile/condovox/platforms/ios/build/emulator/CondoVox.app/CondoVox normal x86_64
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 65).

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2
Cordova Platforms  : ios 5.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-sim           : 7.0.0 
Node              : v10.15.1
npm               : 6.4.1 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/brunodourado/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: I removed the wkkeyboard plugin and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

And see if it helps